# Why NSMutableData change address of pointer?

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

I want to quick preallocate memory and have it wrapped by `NSMutableData` but with access via pointer.
So I have this:

```
var vertex = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(numberOfVertex * 3)
vertex.initialize(0)
vertexData = NSMutableData(bytesNoCopy: vertex, length: numberOfVertex * 3 * sizeof(Float))
```

But when I check address of `vertex` pointer I see different value then `vertexData.bytes` so as I understand I can't use pointer anymore to change data by index.
How to avoid this and have only one memory block?

Comment: This is more an issue of the Foundation framework, independent of the used language (Swift or Objective-C).

Comment: @MartinR should I remove question since it is a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think there is a need to remove the question, duplicates are not generally a bad thing. It helps other people coming from Swift to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you cannot use `NSMutableData` with the no-copy flag that way actually:

> NSMutableData responds to these methods, too, but the bytes are
>   copied anyway and the buffer is freed immediately.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000717-149014